# Can I use the Schur basis returned by ARPACK in a restart capacity?

Tags: arpack

Reading ARPACK documentation, I see that ARPACK will return an "orthogonal basis for the invariant subspace corresponding to the eigenvalues in D" if eigenvectors are not requested. Can this subspace be exploited in some kind of restart capacity? Documentation discusses restarts but I'm not sure how these have been implemented in the routines.

I know you can set the residue vector to an initial guess, but I'd like to know if a pre-generated subspace can be used.

Comment: Upon a restart, you should be able to deflate your initial residual against that converged set, to force convergence to other (smaller? interior?) eigenpairs. You should also be able to do the same thing within your "callback" / reverse communication matvec.